# C++11を使用したジョブシステムの実装方法について

Tags: c++, c++11

お世話になっております。

ゲームで使用する為の
std::threadを使ったジョブシステムが作れないと考えています。
想定しているインタフェースとしては以下の通りです。

```
// コア数を指定してその分std::threadを生成
int threadNum = 8;
JobManager.Create( threadNum );

//実行時
int num = 10000;
// 実行(オブジェクト数、関数ポインタ、void*のデータ).
JobManager.Start( num, pFunc, pData);
// 待機.
JobManager.Join();
```

std::threadは、コンストラクタの時点で関数ポインタを渡さなければならず
また、スレッド生成時にはかなりのコストがかかる為
ゲームのように毎フレームStart()、Join()を実行するのは困難だと思います。

std::threadでジョブシステムを実装することは難しいのでしょうか？
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

スレッドの頻繁な生成/消滅によるコストが気になるのであれば、スレッドプールを作ってみてはいかがでしょうか?

あらかじめスレッドをいくつか作ってプールにためておき、必要な時にプールからスレッドを取り出して処理をさせるイメージです。スレッドは処理が終わったらプールに戻り、次の処理を待機します。

ゲームプログラム起動時に一回スレッドプールを作って、プログラム終了まで作り直さなければ、スレッド生成のコストは起動時のみでそれ以降は発生しません。

ざっと検索してみたところ、例えば以下のページが参考になるかもしれません:
https://cutlassfish.wordpress.com/2016/09/14/c-%E3%81%A7-worker-thread-%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3/

Answer (score 1):

質問はC++11とのことですので条件を満たしませんが、C++17ですと[並列アルゴリズム](http://faithandbrave.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/09/27/155500)が導入されています。

```
std::vector<Data> data;
std::for_each(std::execution::par, begin(data), end(data), pFunc);
```

とやると各`data`に対して`pFunc`が並列に実行されます。実装依存かとは思いますが、スレッドプールが使われるのではないかと予想しています。